# How to run powershell command in OnStart of ServiceBase Class in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, service

I'm trying to create a custom windows service and want to run a powershell command on start.
However, the powershell command failed to be triggered but the writing to the file works (so the code actually works but only failing at the powershell portion).
I also fail to get output on my CLI even though I have specified Console.WriteLine()

Please help!!

```
$source = @"
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.IO;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace Testing
{
    public class MyService : System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase
    {
        public MyService()
        {
            ServiceName = "Testing";
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "PowerShell.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -c & Get-Process"; // Works if path has spaces, but not if it contains ' quotes.
            p.Start();
            // Read the output stream first and then wait. (To avoid deadlocks says Microsoft!)
            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            // Wait for the completion of the script startup code, that launches the -Service instance
            p.WaitForExit(); 
            string filePath = @"C:\ProgramData\testing.txt";
            
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
                writer.WriteLine("This is a test file.");
                writer.WriteLine("Writing to file using C#.");
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!"); // Add code to perform actions when the service starts.
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bye, world!"); // Add code to perform actions when the service stops.
        }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(new MyService());
        }
    }
}
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source -Language CSharp -outputAssembly "hello.exe" -OutputType ConsoleApplication -ReferencedAssemblies "System.ServiceProcess.dll"
```

I have tried other alternatives to trigger a powershell command from C# code based on this [blog](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjmubnQgpGFAxU11DgGHVyHDY0QFnoECBsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcode-maze.com%2Fcsharp-run-powershell-script%2F&usg=AOvVaw0UtutN0R8_lqDmGMVqTUQ4&opi=89978449). Unfortunately, none of the suggestions worked.

Comment: What makes you say that the powershell portion failed? are you writing to another file with the actual command or why?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon
Yes i'm writing to a new file in this code here and it creates a new file with those lines when i run Start-Service <Service-Name>
string filePath = @"C:\ProgramData\testing.txt";
       
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
                writer.WriteLine("This is a test file.");
                writer.WriteLine("Writing to file using C#.");
            }

Comment: Im talking about `-c & Get-Process`, what are you actually running as your powershell command? All output from that process is assigned to `output` but then you're never doing anything with it so how do you know the powershell portion of the code didnt work?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon
Apparently based on what I've read, it's supposed to print it out on the command line (?) Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: why don't you add `File.WriteAllText(filePath, output);` and remove `using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))`. You should see the output from `Get-Process` written to your file

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.